# Variável sem inicializar

Tags: c++, variáveis, c++11, c++14, inicialização

Fiz uma função básica de elevar ao quadrado (exercício de um livro), e la eu uso uma variável nomeada de `aux` e a uso para calcular o valor da potência ao quadrado, porém o compilador alega que `aux` não está inicializada, gostaria de entender o porquê e como resolver esse problema.

```
/*fazer uma função que calcule e retorne o valor de um número ao quadrado*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double square (double);

int main ()
{
    double x;
    cout << "Digite um numero:\n";
    cin >> x;

    system ("clear");

    cout << "O numero " << x << " elevado ao quadrado eh: " << square (x) << "\n";
}

double square (double x)
{
    int i;
    double aux;

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        aux = aux + x;
    }

    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Como está compilando? que compilador está usando? A variável está em uso sim.

Comment: Oi @bigown eu uso o Visual Studio 2015 no windows e o terminal no linux aqui uma foto do 'error list' do visual studio
http://i.imgur.com/nr7G0Z6.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código tem um erro e algumas redundâncias (nem digo que dá para fazer esta conta de forma mais simples `x * x`, entendo a experiência), e tirei uma linha para facilitar no ideone, fora isto não é para dar erro:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double square(double x) {
    double aux = 0; // <=========== tinha que inicializar a variável aqui
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        aux += x;
    }
    return aux;
}
int main() {
    double x;
    cout << "Digite um numero:\n";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "O numero " << x << " elevado ao quadrado eh: " << square(x) << "\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/K7aSb7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kkaomnev-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/VarInit.cpp).

Comment: hmmmm compriendi ok obrigado =) e sobre o modo feito o livro pede para fazer assim ao invez de usar mutiplicação. mais uma vez obrigado.